Why does friendship seem transitive with befriended function templates?
Friendship is not supposed to be transitive. That is, my friends cannot access each other's privates (unless they're also friends).
However, with the following function template that is defined inside a befriending class template, this seems to be the case:
template <typename T>
class A {
  template <typename>
  friend class A; // all other A instances are my friend

  int i{}; // some private member

  template <typename U>
  friend int test(A at, A<U> au) { // int test(A<T>, A<U>) is my friend
    return at.i + au.i;
  }
};

int main() {
  A<int> ai;
  A<char> ac;
  test(ai,ac);
}

I stumbled over this in a setting where test was called operator+ but the principle is the same as in this minimal example.
The way I see it A<int> befriends A<char> as well as a free function int test(A<int>, A<char>). Which means that those can access A<int>::i. However, A<char> in turn befriends some hypothetical function int test(A<char>, A<int>) but I don't see it befriending int test(A<int>, A<char>) anywhere. Crucially, test is not a member function of any A, despite being defined inside A's body.
Yet, int test(A<int>, A<char>) can access both A<int>::i and A<char>::i, despite both being private.
Both gcc and clang seem to accept this. Which means that I misunderstood something. Or both compilers are in error, which is probably not the case.
Note that they both stop accepting the code if one removes the friendship with other A instances unless one also moves the function template definition past the class template.
What friendship rules dictate that this example is legal? I'm assuming C++23.

Some variations: this fails on both and this succeeds on both

@Caleth: Good point, I'll add this to the question.

@MarekR What problems do you mean? Inside of the function body the enclosing class is always considered to be complete, I think?

I suspect this is a bug in Clang and GCC. Presumably both internally fake inline friend function definitions as inline static member definitions and then tweak their scope. (MSVC doesn't compile the snippet.)

@MarekR Naah, I do this all the time with operators. As I believe some standard library implementations do.

This (friend definition inside of a class) could even be beneficial, because it removes the function from non-ADL lookup (so hopefully better build times?)...

@Sneftel I always rather assume I'm wrong than both clang and gcc, but maybe this is one of the rare cases? Anyways, MSVC, in my personal experience, is wrong so often, I wouldn't take it as confirmation either way.

@HolyBlackCat godd spot: looks like it

@bitmask That used to be my assumption about MSVC as well. It's shifted over the last few years.

How does this even compile?  test isn't a free function, and it's private to the class.

@MarkRansom No, the friend in front of it turns it into a free function that is a friend of this class. It's a great language feature.

This is CWG1699.
[class.access.base]/5.2 says:

A member m is accessible at the point R when named in class N if:

m as a member of N is private, and R occurs in a direct member or friend of class N


but it is not clear whether an access from the body of a friend function defined within a class C is considered to 'occur in' C for the purpose of this definition.
From the issue:

There are two lines of analysis that lead to opposite conclusions. The first is that a friend defined within the member-specification is written by the class author and is effectively part of the class, not subject to hijacking by other declarations, and thus should be afforded the same access as all other declarations that are part of the class. The second is that giving different access to a friend function based simply on whether it was defined inside or outside of its befriending class is confusing.


Not sure I follow. So, R is the body of test, right? And N here would be A<char> and m would be A<char>::i in my example. So because test "occurs" in A<int> which is a friend of A<char> this means that therefore test is allowed to access A<char>::i?

That's one interpretation, yes: R is within the body of test, which lexically occurs within the definition of A<int>, a friend of A<char>.

That's kinda exactly the opposite of "friendship is not transitive". How quaint.
